# Creating custom html text boxes

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Just wondering how you would go about creating the effect as seen in the following image:

[Image](http://tothepc.com/pic/tumblr-map-xml-sitemap-creation.png)

The part i'd like to attempt to recreate is the gradient within the text field itself along with the line border surrounding the text box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be done using CSS3, reducing the need to load images. The problem, of course, is that it can become a little tricky cross-browser.

Heres a demo: [Demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/584_form/demo.html)

Heres a tutorial on reproducing the demo: [Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/design-a-prettier-web-form-with-css-3/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+nettuts+(NETTUTS))

Comment: nice reply, just what was needed

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the CSS attributes on the input element in question. `background-image` for the gradient and `border` for the border.